# double array not allowing me to insert input

Tags: java

my for loop wont let me use the counter to add a double into my array. i am getting errors after i define the counter in the for loop, and when i try to use the counter to add a string converted to a double into my array.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab13 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        double[] priceArray = {0, 0, 0, 0};

        for(int counter = 0, counter < priceArray.length, counter++)        
            System.out.println("Please enter a price");
            Double priceArray[counter] = Double.parseDouble(input.nextLine());


    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you think you can omitt the curly braces on the `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `Double` declaration from `priceArray[counter]` in your loop. The array has already been declared, so you don't need the reference type.

Comment: thanks that fixed one issue, but not where i use the counter variable

Comment: Include braces for your for loop. The issue with your for loop is that you're using `,` (comma) instead of `;` (semicolon).